# Ajax Data sending to php file returns null

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm new to ajax and I wanted to store some data from anyone who use my script. My goal is to send data and store it from different users with a json format.

```
$(".btn-play").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
        url: 'http://reapersplace.tk/iplist.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
      action: 'add',
      teamname: $('#clantag').val(),
      partycode: $('#joinPartyToken').val(),
      username: $('#nick').val(),
    },
      dataType:"json",
    success: function(msg, string, jqXHR) {
      $("#playerslist").html(msg.username+"<br>"+msg.teamname+"<br>"+msg.partycode);
    }
    });
});
```

This is my php code:

```
$username=$_REQUEST['username'];
$teamname=$_REQUEST['teamname'];
$partycode=$_REQUEST'partycode'];
$list = array('username' =>$username , 'teamname'=>$teamname,'partycode'=>$partycode);
$c= json_encode($list);
echo $c;
?>
```

The result is always null.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the content type in your php:  `header('Content-type:  application/json;charset=UTF-8');` ?  Not sure if that will help.  It would be good to see the network activity in your browser developer tools.

Comment: nothing changed. the result is always {"username":null,"teamname":null,"partycode":null}

Comment: have you tried to print $_REQUEST directly? Check if any data is coming at all to the variables? rest of your code looks good.

Comment: the data actually store but for a second that i cant reach with refreshing i guess. look at this http://i.imgur.com/4NRbxuM.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your data correctly.  Try using `$.param()` to do that:

```
[...]
data: $.param({
    action: 'add',
    teamname: $('#clantag').val(),
    partycode: $('#joinPartyToken').val(),
    username: $('#nick').val(),
}),
[...]
```

Comment: When you say "nothing changed," where are you looking?  Are you error_logging the fields in php to see what it received?

Comment: im looking to the php file.. it should echo the info instead of giving null. On network tool for chrome i saw the response(http://i.imgur.com/4NRbxuM.png) but i don't know why the php doesn't keep the values

Comment: Please try to be specific with what you are doing, and what you are expecting to see, and where.  The image with the response shows a GET request (or it appears to be one anyway), not a POST request as you have in your code.  It also shows that the php file appeared to recognize your (GET/urlencoded) parameters, and that it returned them correctly.  How are you expecting php to "keep the values?"  Also, simply "looking to the php file" does not show you any values it received.  With patience, we'll figure this out :D

Comment: I wanted to see a database to store a certain number of username's data. Then i was trying to use json encode to make it easier to get those values later. Can you explain me what method is better or how to store data to get it later with an ajax?

Comment: Ah!  In that case, you would typically use the POST method to create, and GET to retrieve it afterwards (you can look at $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] to see which one it is).  With GET, you would append `?id=123` to the "url" $.ajax parameter to specify which item you want to retrieve.  With POST, you specify `data: $.param(obj)` for what you want to create.  Generally, after creating a row in a table, you would want to return the id in the response.  But this is getting much bigger than the original question :D